# Why does the like box show the wrong "page"

Tags: facebook-social-plugins

This is a little complex, please bear with me.

We've implemented the like box and the issue is about what page shows up. There is a company page and a "place" page.

When I am logged into FB, the stream from an associated place page is displayed.

If however, I start a fresh browser and do not log into FB, the stream from the company page is displayed. The ID number is from the company page.

The behavior happens on two pages http://TheVillageCup.com/community.php and http://CarolinesVT.com/community.php

Comment: Can you post some more information?  Code samples of what you have tried, links to where we can confirm this behavior...etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that this has something to do with the code you've placed on your page.  For the [Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/), it asks for a facebook page url.

However, in the loading of the JS SDK, it's asking for an app id.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=**APP ID**";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div 
   class="fb-like-box" 
   data-href="**FacebookPageUrl**"  
   data-width="292"  
   data-show-faces="true"  
   data-stream="true"  
   data-header="true"> 
</div>
```

So in your case, is there an issue with any other facebook plugins on the page interfering with that id?

Comment: This the only Fb plugin on the site

Answer (score 0):

"*The behavior happens on two pages http://TheVillageCup.com and http://CarolinesVT.com*"

You seem to be using `AddThis` which is made by a third-party.

Also I see no like box plugin being used on either URL you gave. The Addthis is displaying a like plugin of sorts, but it is not the like box plug in.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

vs

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

You should contact the AddThis vendor to see why they've done what they've done.

Comment: I was told by my developer that he used the standard Fb API. I will bring this back to him.

Comment: I just looked at the source and I see only the Fb like box.php. I don't see anything about a third party plugin

Comment: Never mind I see the issue . You need to look at the community page.

Comment: I get the like-box on the community page showing the Caroline's Fine Dining on facebook wether or not I'm logged into Facebook or not.  How can I reproduce?

Comment: It's clearer on the village cup site. The company page talksmabout the routes of American cuisine. The place page has my last checkin about chicken and waffles. Which page displays seems to based on whether one is logged in to Fb or not. When I get to my desk I'll post screen shots.